# Python Request Taking Much Longer Than Expected

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to scrape from this URL that returns a JSON file.

The page loads in less than a second on my browser but takes about 10 seconds using requests. Any suggestions on why it takes so long and how to change that?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://www.lowes.com/IntegrationServices/resources/storeLocator/json/v2_0/stores?langId=-1&storeId=10702&catalogId=10051&place=10001&count=25'

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers )
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
site_json = json.loads(soup.text)


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(site_json)

first_row = pd.Series(df.iloc[0]['Location'])

print(first_row)
```

(I am also aware that I am probably doing extra steps when converting it to a database, I am used to scraping from an HTML... and this still works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, changing the user-agent seems to fix the issue, e.g.:

```py
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 12871.102.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.141 Safari/537.36"
}
```

Perhaps the issue has something to do with Lowes' API server denying or delaying responses to unrecognized/uncommon user-agents. A list of current Chrome user-agent values can be found [here](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/chrome-os?utm_source=whatismybrowsercom&utm_medium=internal&utm_campaign=latest-user-agent-index).